# How to select all rows in Qtable Widget when i press a pushbutton?

Tags: c++, qt4

```
ui->xvalue->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->xvalue->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

with these two lines I could able to select the rows in the table. But now what I need is when I click a push button "I want all the rows to be selected in the table".

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()  // Select all rows push button
{
ui->xvalue->selectionModel()->???
}
```

I don't know how to proceed further to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`QTableWidget` inherits the `selectAll` function from [`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectAll), so it's actually quite simple. Assuming ui->xvalue is a `QTableWidget`, your code will look like this:

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()  // Select all rows push button
{
    ui->xvalue->selectAll();
}
```